# using Lookup or vloopup

Tags: excel, vlookup, lookup

I have an excel file with multiple tabs. In picture 1 I want this box to display whichever X from another sheet. For example if 'Customer' has the X, the highlight box will say customer.

Can anyone make this simple for me, do not have much experience with this.

[image: Picture 1]

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example IF statement that you can tailor to your needs. It looks over your grid and returns the value in column A if column B contains an "x".

`=IF(B3="x",A3,(IF(B4="x",A4,(IF(B5="x",A5,(IF(B6="x",A6,"")))))))`